# Speed up the code

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to speed up the following code. A program should find the prevalent number in a string. This is the number, which appears in a string for more than

> len(string)/2

times. The challenge is that the input file consists of a random number of strings, each can contain several thousands numbers. I've tried the brute force approach

```
for line in lst:
    nline = line.split(',')
    m = [i for i in nline if nline.count(i) > len(nline)/2]
    print(m[0] if len(m) > 0 else "None")
```

and it yielded about 10 seconds of runtime.

The fastest version runs for about 0.8 seconds

```
for line in lst:
    nline = line.split(',')
    d = collections.Counter(nline)
    n = dict()
    m = [i for i, n in d.items() if n > len(nline)/2]
    print(m[0] if len(m) > 0 else "None")
```

Are there any ways to further increase performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would use the `.most_common(1)` member function of `collections.Counter`

```
for line in lst:
    ...
    d = collections.Counter(nline)
    m = d.most_common(1)
    print( "None" if m is None else m[0] )
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common

Although I don't think that there will be much speed to be gained. The heavy lifting is the frequency counting of all elements in `nline`.

Comment: Thanks for most_common, haven't figured it out. However, it's hardly gives any performance advantage. Just as you've said.